# AOT error: require is not defined (caused by ng2-dragula library)

Tags: angular, requirejs, angular2-aot, dragula, ng2-dragula

I have an angular 2 application and am using ng2-dragula library. Everything is working in development (JIT compilation) mode. When I compile with AOT, the aot build and rollup are successful, but then I get this error in the browser:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at dragula.js:3
at main-aot.js:6
```

This error comes from these lines at the top of dragula.js file.

```
var emitter = require('contra/emitter');
var crossvent = require('crossvent');
var classes = require('./classes');
```

I tried adding requirejs to my project, and then I got this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "contra/emitter" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
```

http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded

So I went to the require page "common errors" and tried following some of their suggestions and then got this error between two non-dragula related scripts

```
Mismatched anonymous define() module: blah blah
```

but these work fine by themselves in AOT when require.js isnt added to the project.

Is there a way to modify those require statements to make this work in AOT? Why am I not getting this error in JIT compilation? Pretty stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to add node_modules/dragula/** to the commonjs include section of rollup-config plugins section (also had to add atoa/**, ticky/**, contra/**, because dragula uses them I think.)